# Is the necessity of the ferrite core on a PS2 controller cable a function of the length of the cable?

Tags: ferrite, ferrite-bead

I'm connecting a wired PS2 controller to an ESP32.
The controllers come with 2 meter cables that have ferrite cores at their connector end.
I will be shortening to 5cm and soldering to a 5cm ribbon cable.
It's not a big deal to move the core down to sit on the 5cm that I am leaving, but it will take up space in the project box.
So to the original question. Is the core needed because of the length of the cable or is it always advisable?

Comment: It was only needed to pass EMC requirements in the original setup. Yours is totally different. Remove the ferrite if needed.

Comment: @winny Cool, thanks. I will and test it. If there's no issue I will answer my own question with the results. I appreciate your time.

Comment: No worries mate. Moreover, said EMI would definitely come from the PS2 itself and the controller (cable) act as an antenna to aid radiation of said disturbance, not the other way around.

Comment: @winny good to know. I don't know the engineering side of things, just bit banging.